# bulk update and insert in mongoose and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to create and update list of item in nodejs , if item has exist update that and if not exsist it add them in database and if item has exist in database and not exist in list , remove that item from database .

in first time i send this list to server :

```
intrestName: [
{ name: '11' },
{ name: '22' }, 
{ name: '33' },
{ name: '44' }]
```

in first time i want to add all of this item to save in database with this code :

```
    await IntrestModel.updateMany({},{$set:{...item.intrestName}}, { upsert: true });
```

but it not add any thing in datbase .

whats the problem ? how  can i sovle this problem ????

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `insertMany` method of mongoose. `updateMany` it's for update records already in database, but it's not your case

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany

**EDIT**

```js
intrestNames = [
  { name: '11' },
  { name: '22' }, 
  { name: '33' },
  { name: '44' }
]

await Promise.all(
  intrestNames.map((intrestName) => {
    return IntrestModel.updateOne(intrestName, {$set: intrestName}, { upsert: true })
 })
)
```

Comment: i want use this for update and insert . for this reason i use the Update

Comment: the match query in your update is empty, it will never find anything. Also if you want to update multiple records, with different values, you have to implement a for loop, updateMany can only update multiple records but still with the same value

Comment: I put un example in the answer

Comment: if you're using mongoose database transaction, move the Promise.all into a synchronous for loop, to avoid writeConflict

Comment: if it doesn't fit your needs, you have to be more clear about what's you're trying to do. If you want to update multiple records with different names, you cannot use updateMany, but you have to update every single record. If you want to do something else, be more clear

Comment: I forgot a `(` if the problem was that